# Relationship table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to step up my knowledge of MySQL and how a relationship can work between a few different tables in a database.  I understand primary and foreign keys and how those work within tables.

What I have is a test database I am playing with full of `people`, `hats` and the relationship between different hats and people.  Here is what I have so far in my test database:

```
| Tables_in_test  |
+-----------------+
| hats            |
| hats_collection |
| people          |
+-----------------+
```

My `people` table looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| person_id | fname   |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 | Sethen  |
|         2 | Michael |
|         3 | Jazmine |
+-----------+---------+
```

My `hats` table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+
| hat_id | hat      |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Awesome  |
|      2 | Kick Ass |
|      3 | Bowler   |
|      4 | Fedora   |
+--------+----------+
```

And finally my `hats_collection` table looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------+
| person_id | hat_id |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |      1 |
|         2 |      4 |
|         3 |      2 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Essentially, I am storing all of the different hats that could exist in the hats table and holding their relationship to different people in the `hats_collection` table which just uses the `person_id` and `hat_id`.

While I am sure how to set up all of these tables correctly and insert the data, I am unsure on how to write the query to display the data from the `hats_collection` table to display a users name and which hat they have.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT people.fname, hats.hat
FROM people
INNER JOIN hats
INNER JOIN hats_collection
ON hats_collection.person_id = people.person_id AND hats_collection.hat_id = hats.hat_id
WHERE people.person_id = 1;
```

Which is returning an empty set.

My questions are these:

1. How would I change my query to get the correct results of which people have which hats?
2. Is this the way I would set up the tables for something like this?  Is there an easier/more efficient way?

**EDIT**

My apologies, the query I posted works.  It was returning an empty set because the person with the id of 1 doesn't have any hats, but this has spawned a new question:

1. Is this the best way to write this query?

My question about being the most efficient way to do this still stands.

Comment: This is known as a many-to-many relationship, and `hats_collection` is a cross reference table. You will often see table names like `people_hats` or `people_hats_xref`.

Comment: @criticalfix Thanks for that information.  Is this common practice??

Comment: Yes, this is standard practise. It is the correct way to set up the relationship. Your xref table can have a composite PK that consists of the two FK columns, or you can have an additional PK column separate from the two FK columns.

Comment: Yes it is.  With regards to your join, this site has a great working example of different join types http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Beware of joins like `INNER JOIN hats` without an `ON` clause. That's a cross join, or cartesian join, and it returns one row for each combinations of rows in the joined tables. Cross joining two thousand-record tables will return a million records. You rarely want this. I have seen this sort of thing cause serious problems in a production environment. Always make sure there's an `ON` clause, even if it's `ON 1=1`, just so the next person who looks at the code knows that you did this on purpose.

Comment: Best practice is to order join tables logically and put each tables join condition into the `ON` part of that `JOIN` to keep things clear. Like I've done in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria for the ON should be on each join otherwise you get what's called a cross join all records in people to all records in hats, which isn't what you wanted.

```
SELECT people.fname, hats.hat
FROM people
INNER JOIN hats_collection
  ON hats_collection.person_id = people.person_id 
INNER JOIN hats
  ON hats_collection.hat_id = hats.hat_id
WHERE people.person_id = 1;
```

Tables are designed in a "normal/common practice"

Now if you want all people regardless if they have hats or not... use `LEFT JOIN` instead of inner's above.

Comment: And using `INNER JOIN` like this is completely acceptable?  I mean, using it twice like you have it?

Answer (score 2):

Person with id=1 does not have any hats so this is fine.

If you want to display persons even when they dont have any hats you have to use `LEFT JOIN` instead

```
SELECT people.fname, GROUP_CONCAT(hats.hat) AS hats
  FROM people
  LEFT JOIN hats_collection ON hats_collection.person_id = people.person_id
  LEFT JOIN hats ON hats_collection.hat_id = hats.hat_id
 GROUP BY people.person_id;
```

Notice how I reordered joined tables logically and put each relevant join condition to its own join tables `ON` part.

Comment: What does the `GROUP_CONCAT` line do?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat  it basically generates a seperated list of results combining all that persons hats onto one row in the result set instead of having different rows.

Comment: @xQbert I see, it delimits the results with a `,` in one row next to the name.  Why would I do this instead of having different rows though?  Seems like I would have to write more logic in the server side to separate all of them out like this.

Comment: This was just for an example. If you need them separately then ofcourse you don't use group_concat and group by. All depends of needs.

Comment: @SethenMaleno sometimes you just want a separated list; and if you do, the DB can do the lifting for you it's going to be far more efficient than what you can do in code from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the WHERE clause in your select statement to show people with their hats.  According to the sample data, person_id = 1 doesn't have a hat.